# Relative paths in windows batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, exe, relative-path

This seems to be the directory where my batch file `my-build` resides.

```
Program\
       my_app\
              javasdk\
                 java-build.bat
              app\
                  my-build.bat
```

I want to run from my batch file

```
1. Move one level up and run java-build.bat
2. And then run one more command in app dir
```

I tried

```
cd .. 
javasdk\java-build
cd..
app\my-build
app- antbuild.bat -D env.myAppjars= C:\Source\abcd\my-app\app\lib
```

I am getting some errors.

Am I doing it correct?
How can I use relative path instead

```
C:\Source\abcd\my-app\app\lib
```

Comment: Relative to where? _Is the current working directory `C:\Source\abcd\my-app\app\lib`?_ Also unless the scripts specifically need to be run when they're in the current working directory then there's no need to keep changing it. To run a batch file from another you should probably be using the `Call` command.

Comment: `"1. Move one level up and run java-build.bat"` Move one level up from where? Please provide the full path to directory that you want to move one level up from. You also showed 2 different directory trees : `Program\my_app\app` and `C:\Source\abcd\my-app\app\lib` they do not match so it is not clear whether you are referring to the same `my_app` directory or they are 2 different directories.

Answer (score 0):

You are in `C:\Source\abcd\my-app\javasdk` and want a relative path to `C:\Source\abcd\my-app\app`?
Go one up and then down the other path:

```
cd /d "C:\Source\abcd\my-app\javasdk"
echo you are in %cd%
dir "..\app"
```

To go "two up" use `..\..` and so on.

Also use `call` to call another batchfile. If you just execute it with it's Name, there is no return to the calling file.